# Limit Command on HBase Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

There are few method to limit result from scan method on hbase using filter

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(new PageFilter(limit));
scan.setFilter(filterList);
```

or using setBatch

```
scan.setBatch(limit);
scan.next();
```

What I want to ask are :

1. which case is better to use in which scenario?
2. Which one give better performance?
3. Is there any better way to use limit?

I am using hbase client api 1.0.0 and HBase 1.0.0-cdh5.6.0

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456876/hbase-scan-operation-caching . Also [Scan.html#setMaxResultSize(long)](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.3/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setMaxResultSize(long))

Comment: I make simple test and by far setMaxResultSize is the worst.

Comment: Ouch! What version of hbase are you using. Go through the cloudera [docs](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hbase_scanning.html) on reading from HBase. An excerpt from it :   *"When you use setCaching and setMaxResultSize together, single server requests are limited by either number of rows or maximum result size, whichever limit comes first."*

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using HBase 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I would go with setBatch, due that it's predefined, but it may cause lag issues.